# Maven version and java version conflict

Tags: java, maven

I can only use java 1.6 for my project. So maven version also has to be 2.2.1 . Cannot use maven 3.0. But while building I'm getting following error :

```
 Error resolving version for 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin':Plugin requires Maven version 3.0
```

this is the pom:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
</plugin>
```

what are the version that we can use?

Comment: You could simply download maven 3.x and set MAVEN_HOME to 3.x

Comment: use 3.2.5 is the latest version as per this [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html)

Comment: Just use an older version of the jar-plugin, e.g. `<version>2.0</version>`

Comment: First of all, why do you set the maven-jar-plugin to Java 8, when you want Java6? Secondly, you can run Maven and compile everything with Java 8, but build _for_ Java 6. This means that the resulting jar will run with Java 6.

Comment: First why are you coming to the conclusion that you can only use Maven 2.2.1 for Java 1.6  and 3.2.5 ? You can most recent version of Maven 3.6.3 and use JDK 7 and set source/target to JDK 6 or even better use JDK 9+ and use `release` option..or you can alternative use toolchains....

Comment: Ah oversight. Setting a maven-jar-plugin to source/target does not work cause maven-jar-plugin has no such configuration and if even want to set you have to use maven-compiler-plugin ...

Answer (score 0):

Changes the source and target to 1.6. If your code does not make use of java8 features then it should work just fine. This will generate a jar that is compatible with any java6 codebase.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
</plugin>
```